# Native Alternative to Windows Explorer File Copy?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I am using Windows 10, and I often have to copy files from mapped network drives, and the connection to these remote drives is very dodgy.

Copying from them is very slow, and can fail randomly and/or completely freeze and crash explorer.

I am looking for a more robust copying program?  One that allows pause and resume, and can handle failures without having to completely restart the copy. (like all the features Bit torrent, or other download managers can give you)

I know these features are possible, because I implemented my own simple console app that does it just using the standard win32 apis.

But is there a program with a GUI baked into Windows that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: for example, I have resorted to right click dragging files and doing 7Z 'compress to here' using 'store' just so 7z does the copying and exporer wont freeze...

Comment: I use Altap Salamander, try otehr tools like Total commander

Comment: XCOPY is a command line tool, built into windows, which will allow you to resume file transfers if they fail, has MANY features specific to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Robocopy has a [resume feature](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html):

> /Z : Copy files in restartable mode (survive network glitch).

[Derk A. Benisch wrapped it in a GUI](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) good enough to be spotlighted on TechNet. Hope that makes it okay that I haven't used it before.

I normally use Robocopy by doing more than one run and setting the retry and timeout values to zero. But I guess you can set those flags to values appropriate for your network (retry as much as possible, timeout at some reasonable interval).

Robocopy ships with Windows since Vista, but if it's missing from your system [the command line tool is available from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657).

Comment: Every version of Windows since Vista comes with Robocopy already included.

Comment: @CharlesBurge Ahh, that explains how I got them.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a web server on one of the machines. HTTP provides fairly robust error checking for file transfers. There are literally hundreds of options for which server to use. I'd suggest something that supports PHP (or your favorite scripting language) so that you can make (or more likely download) a nice interface for it.

FTP, SFTP, SCP are other similar options but HTTP is more flexible than any of these, of course.